# Generating a Linux executable with Mono with mkbundle

Tags: executable, mono

A C# file in mono can be compiled using `gmcs` command. This will create a `hello.exe` file.

```
$ gmcs hello.cs
$ ls
hello.cs  hello.exe
$ ./hello.exe
Hello from Mono!
```

To generate a linux executable, I tried this command, but it generates the error:

```
$ gmcs /t:exe hello.cs /out:hello

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Module file name 'hello' must have file extension.
```

I want create a standalone executable so that I can execute it simply run it by saying and I get the desired output:

```
$ ./hello
Hello from Mono!
```

I searched and found a solution which mentions of a tool called [mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications#Bundles):

```
$ mkbundle -o hello hello.exe --deps
Sources: 1 Auto-dependencies: True
embedding: /home/ed/Projects/hello_world/hello.exe
embedding: /mono/lib/mono/1.0/mscorlib.dll
Compiling:
as -o /tmp/tmp54ff73e6.o temp.s
cc -o hello -Wall temp.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono` /tmp/tmp54ff73e6.o
Done

$ ls -l
total 3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ed users 1503897 2005-04-29 11:07 hello
-rw-r--r--  1 ed users     136 2005-04-29 11:06 hello.cs
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ed users    3072 2005-04-29 11:06 hello.exe
```

This utility does not seem to exist in my Mono install. I found that this is available in `mono-devel` package. To install this package meant installing around 82 other packages. My goal was to keep my mono install minimal until sometime.

Is there a way to install `mkbundle` standalone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was very impatient and felt that the package `mono-2.0-devel` might have mkbundle. So I went ahead and installed `mono-2.0-devel` which needed only 18 additional packages. When I typed `mkb` and hit tab, it showed me `mkbundle2`.

I tried:

```
$ mkbundle2 -o hello hello.exe --deps
OS is: Linux
Sources: 1 Auto-dependencies: True
   embedding: /home/minato/Projects/Practice/mono/hello.exe
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll
Compiling:
as -o temp.o temp.s 
cc -ggdb -o hello -Wall temp.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono`  temp.o
Done

$ ls
hello  hello.cs  hello.e  hello.exe

$ ./hello
Hello from Mono!
```

This was what I needed in the first place.

Thanks to the `command-not-found` tool.

Comment: That `hello.e` was a result of an earlier typo in the parameter for `/out:filename`

Comment: In case you're using a Debian-based system: You can search for file names in packages with `apt-file`, e.g. `apt-file search mkbundle`. This tells me that mkbundle is in package mono-devel (I'm on Ubuntu 11.10).